# Bootstrap container content does not center when window is shrunk

Tags: css, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap, flexbox

I am in the process of developing a BootStrap wrapper for an `ASP.NET` website that works with almost everything I have used in it -- with the only exception being that content in the main panel **does not center itself** properly when shrinking the browser window's width, despite the header and footer being completely responsive.

I have a fiddle for this problem: https://dotnetfiddle.net/6dmcaX.

**PLEASE NOTE** that this wrapper is applied to the master page, and not directly onto the pages that I'm testing with.

For the header, I use a div with the following class attributes: `d-flex justify-content-center flex-md-rows align-items-center shadow-sm border-menus fixed-top`. Inside that is an `UpdatePanel` and `ContentTemplate`, with holds a bunch of markup for the BootStrap `navbar`.

Meanwhile, here is the markup for the main content panel:

```
<div class="container d-flex justify-content-center flex-md-rows align-items-center">
// the container acts the same with or without the text to the right of "d-flex"
    <div id="content" class="row" style="margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;">
        <div id="divContMain" runat="server" style="width: auto;">
            <asp:UpdatePanel ID="contentUPanel" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
                <ContentTemplate>
                    <center>
                        <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="MainContent" runat="server" />
                    </center>
                </ContentTemplate>
            </asp:UpdatePanel>
        </div>
    …
    </div>
</div>
```

The container `divContMain` needs to run on the server because just below the main content is a sidebar which may or may not be needed, depending on the page being called. By default, the class for `divContMain` is `col-12`. One thing I tried doing to fix this problem was I changed the main container to a `container-fluid` and changed `divContMain`'s width to be inherited instead of "auto" -- and while this did a better job keeping contents in the center, it eventually stops working once the window gets small enough.

I'm very close to figuring this one out, but I wanted to ask and see if anyone else knew. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Do you want to center `Purchasing Requisitions` text?

Comment: @StepUp I want it to be centered within its container, yes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With some help from [StepUp](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1646240/stepup), I was able to find out what exactly was going wrong. The main `container` needs its position set to *absolute* and the content group just below the container needs its content justified to the center, like this:

```
<div class="container-fluid mt-5" style="position: absolute;">
    <div id="content" class="row" style="display: flex; justify-content: center;">
        …
    </div>
</div>
```

Now everything scales and is properly centered!

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to use combination of [the Bootstrap classes](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/flex/) to justify content when `display: flex` is used:

```
d-flex justify-content-center
```

So you can add new css class for `h1`:

```
#MainContent_ctl00 > h1 {
  text-align: center;
}
```

and add `d-flex justify-content-center` styles for `div` which contains your table:

```
<div class="container d-flex justify-content-center" style="overflow-x: visible;">
    <table class="datatable datatable-striped" 
       id="MainContent_dgReqs" style="border-collapse:collapse;"
       border="1" rules="all" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="5">
        <!-- The other code is omitted for the brevity -->
    </table>
</div>
```

In addition, text can be aligned through `text-align: center` inside of `<h1>`.

An example:

```css
.tableint {
  font-size: 15px;
  font-family: Estrangelo Edessa, Verdana;
  border: Solid 1px #666666;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  color: Black;
}

.thint {
  background-color: #EE8322;
  color: Black;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 14px;
  border: solid 1px #666666;
  border-collapse: separate;
  font-variant: small-caps;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.textboxint {
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
  border: 1px solid #d1c7ac;
  font-size: 14px;
  border-style: inset;
  margin-right: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  margin-top: 5px;
  font-family: Estrangelo Edessa, Verdana;
  color: Black;
  width: 175px;
}

.dropdownint {
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
  border: 1px solid #d1c7ac;
  font-size: 12px;
  border-style: inset;
  margin-right: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  margin-top: 5px;
  font-family: Estrangelo Edessa, Verdana;
  color: Black;
  width: 175px;
}

.buttonint {
  margin: 5px;
  font-family: Estrangelo Edessa, Verdana;
  font-size: 14px;
  background-color: #EE8322;
  color: Black;
  text-align: center;
  border-top-style: groove;
  border-left-style: groove;
  border-right-color: Black;
  border-bottom-color: Black;
  height: 22px;
}

.buttonint:hover {
  font-family: Estrangelo Edessa, Verdana;
  font-size: 14px;
  background-color: #FFFFCC;
  color: #006699;
  margin: 5px;
}

#MainContent_ctl00 > h1 {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="container-fluid my-hs d-flex justify-content-center flex-md-rows align-items-center">
    <div class="row justify-content-center" id="content"
      style="margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; padding-top: 1rem;">
      <!-- <div id="divContMain" style="width: inherit;">may just remove -->
      <div id="contentUPanel">
        <div id="MainContent_ctl00">
          <br>
          <h1>Purchasing Requisitions</h1>
          <br>
          <div>
            <table width="325" align="center" class="tableint" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="5">
              <tbody>
                <tr>
                  <td align="center" class="thint" colspan="2">Filter</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td align="left" style="width: 50%">Request Start:</td>
                  <td align="left" style="width: 50%">
                    <input class="textboxint" style="width:175px;" type="text">
                  </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td align="left" style="width: 50%">Request End:</td>
                  <td align="left" style="width: 50%">
                    <input class="textboxint" style="width:175px;" type="text">
                  </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td align="left" style="width: 50%">Part Number:</td>
                  <td align="left" style="width: 50%">
                    <input class="textboxint" style="width:175px;" type="text"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td align="left" style="width: 50%">Account:</td>
                  <td align="left" style="width: 50%">
                    <input class="textboxint" style="width:175px;" type="text"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td align="left" style="width: 50%">Vendor No:</td>
                  <td align="left" style="width: 50%">
                    <input class="textboxint" style="width:175px;" type="text"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td align="left" style="width: 50%">Vendor Name:</td>
                  <td align="left" style="width: 50%">
                    <input class="textboxint" style="width:175px;" type="text"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td align="center" colspan="2">
                    <input class="buttonint" type="submit" value="Search">
                  </td>
                </tr>
              </tbody>
            </table>
          </div>
          <br>
          <div class="container d-flex justify-content-center" style="overflow-x: visible;">
            <table class="datatable datatable-striped" id="MainContent_dgReqs" style="border-collapse:collapse;"
              border="1" rules="all" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="5">
              <tbody>
                <tr align="center" class="thint" style="color:Black;background-color:#EE8322;font-weight:bold;">
                  <td>Row1</td>
                  <td>Row2</td>
                  <td>Row3</td>
                </tr>
                <tr align="center" class="gridview">
                  <td>Data1</td>
                  <td>Data2</td>
                  <td>Data3</td>
                </tr>
                <tr align="center" class="gridview" style="background-color:#FFE1CD;">
                  <td>Data1</td>
                  <td>Data2</td>
                  <td>Data3</td>
                </tr>
              </tbody>
            </table>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>


  <script src=" index.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"
    href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js">
  </script>
```

**UPDATE:**

I saw you edited your fiddle. So the items are aligned, however we need to align the above `div` container. So to do this, it is necessary to add the following styles:

```
<div class="row" id="content mx-auto" style="display:flex; justify-content: center;">

   <!-- The other code is omitted for the brevity -->
</div>
```

Comment: I can't tell what's different here other than the #MainContent tag in the CSS area, and even then that doesn't do anything. Please don't just drop a bunch of text here all at once.

Comment: thanks a lot for the help!! I was able to find out what exactly to do after the content was justified :)